# What is this "Column '^ ' not found' message in data.table::melt?

Tags: r, data.table

MWE:

```
library(data.table) # version 1.9.6
DT = fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rdatatable/data.table/master/vignettes/melt_default.csv")

colA = paste("dob_child", 1:3, sep="")
colB = paste("gender_child", 1:3, sep="")
DT.m2 = melt(DT, measure = list(colA, colB), value.name = c("dob", "gender"))
```

which is code taken from the [data table vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) Section "3. Enhanced (new) functionality".

Running the code gives an error:

```
> DT.m2 = melt(DT, measure = list(colA, colB), value.name = c("dob", "gender"))
Error in melt.data.table(DT, measure = list(colA, colB), value.name = c("dob",  : 
  Column 'ˆ ' not found in 'data'
```

Comment: the dataset doesn't have 'gender_child column

Comment: oh, good point, thanks, I should have downloaded `melt_enhanced.csv` instead. Still I'll leave this up here as the error message was baffling.

Comment: If the value in th 'colB' is not there, you can use only `colA` i.e. `melt(DT, measure = colA, value.name = "dob")`

Comment: Using your code, I get a different error, ie. `Error in melt.data.table(DT, measure = list(colA, colB), value.name = c("dob",  : 
  One or more values in 'measure.vars' is invalid.`

Comment: that is interesting, what version of `data.table` do you have, mine is 1.9.6

Comment: It is 1.9.7, so that may be the reason

Comment: I'm getting same error with 1.9.6 but the vignette says it's demonstrating the features in 1.9.6. There are of course no `gender_child_n` column(s) in that data.table, so the requested operation makes little sense. Is it really in the vignette?

Comment: `names(DT)` returns `[1] "family_id"  "age_mother" "dob_child1" "dob_child2" "dob_child3"`

Comment: Sorry, I was somewhat mistaken when I wrote that. The vignette does indeed contain those lines of code, however what I missed is that the table named `DT` is loaded from two different sources. It is a rather long vignette and I skipped the code in section two which loaded `DT <-  fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rdatatable/data.table/master/vignettes/melt_enhanced.csv")`

Comment: I agree that the operation makes no sense but I guess what ended up being the problem here was the really confusing error message. it looks like it has been fixed in 1.9.7.

Comment: I suppose this might be useful since the CRAN version is 1.9.6, but I have a somewhat vague memory that there were other problems with 1.9.7.